# Save and recall print settings

Tags: printing, vbscript

OK so I'm working on a project that requires saving the printer settings and later recalling them each time a page is printed from the application. After reading for days and trying to get this to work I think I'm missing something from the "big picture".

First, I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express (VB Script), or at least I was trying to but got lost.

The objective is to save the User selected printer settings (possibly a Print Setup dialog) into a variable or array or maybe write to a file or registry, Then later when the user prints a page the previously selected settings are used without the need to re select them with a Print Dialog (preferably suppress the Print dialog). The script does not need to actually print the pages but rather be a Sub or Function that is called from another script. The reason for this is because the script that runs when the user prints  the pages will actually print a few pages with one set of pre selected printer settings THEN will switch printers and settings, including paper size, and then finish printing the remainder of the pages.

Example: User clicks "Print" button, Before printing pages 1 through 3 run Function "PrinterSettings1" then afterwards (and before printing pages 4 - 8) run a second function "PrinterSettings2".

Thanks

EDIT: I prefer it did not have any dependencies that are not included with most versions of windows. Or what I mean is that it does not require a .NET Framework or anything else, but if it's absolutely necessarily then I guess I'll have to make it works.

Comment: Visual Basic 2010 Express is Visual Basic and is a compiled language. VBScript is a scripting language and is interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

We're using setprinter.exe to manipulate printers at logon/logof.  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657
I read about the dependencies; but I doubt there is a way to do this other than calling something like this.